# OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) ... accessing mutiple outside script functions

Tags: c#, triggers, null, return, 2d

So I have this script that affects another script just fine. It's attached to a gameobject (an attack box) that damages another gameobject (an enemy). It makes the enemy GameObject perform an animation (it getting hurt) and takes away a certain amount of health. That's all working fine.

What I'm stuck on is that I'm trying to get it to do the same for more than one type of enemy, therefore, accessing multiple scripts. The scripts are relatively the same and i've tested those out individually and both work fine. But when I try to have my attack box the script is attached to, affect more than one script, I get nothing. I figure it's just the way it's typed out and I've tried several ways already. But I've reverted it back to its most simple form to display it here. How do I get this script to work for both, so I don't have to have multiple scripts attached to one hitbox?

I should mention that in this script, it does access the first script mentioned in the OnTriggerEnter2D function. It just doesn't do it for any other scripts mentioned afterwards.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class slicer : MonoBehaviour {

public int damage = 5;
private foeHP foe;
private goblin gobby;
public float timer;



void Update()
{
    Destroy ();
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {

        other.gameObject.GetComponent<foeHP> ().takeDamage (damage);
        var foe = other.GetComponent<foeHP> ();
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<goblin> ().takeDamage (damage);
        var gobby = other.GetComponent<goblin> ();

    }



    if (foe == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (gobby == null) {
        return;
    }
}

public void Destroy(){
    if (timer <=0)
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a generic Enemy class that all enemy types derive from.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    int health;

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
    }
}
```

Change your enemy classes such that they all derive from `Enemy`

```
public class Goblin : Enemy
{
    // Extra fields/methods
}

public class Foe : Enemy
{
    // Extra fields/methods
}
```

Now you can simplify your checks into:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        other.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(5);
    }
}
```

Since both `Goblin` and `Foe` are type `Enemy`, `GetComponent<Enemy>()` will return their respective derived type and you can call `TakeDamage()` on them.